# Remove shipping address in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

Is there a way to remove the shipping address for a specific product only? Right now there are solution that instruct the removal of shipping address for overall product. But I want it to be done for specific product only. There are product that needs this shipping address but there are also some that do not. Any idea on how to achieve this?

Note: I'm looking for Magento 2 way to do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a virtual or downloadable products which require only billing address during checkout (virtual quote). Another way is to create own product type, but seems like using virtual products is more suitable and easy way.